# OneDrive LastSignInTime Registry to DateTime format

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I am trying to check Last Sign in date/time for a onedrive login script but struggling with converting the decimal value returned into a correct date/time format. Wondering if I could get an assist.

```
$d = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1" -Name "LastSignInTime")
```

this currently returns the following which a GM shows it as a `TypeName: System.Int64`

```
1594662535
```

I have tried various conversion types not exactly knowing how it should be read and so far everything comes back inncorrect to what I would expect.

This

```
[DateTime]::FromFiletime([Int64]::Parse($d))
```

returns

```
Sunday, December 31, 1600 4:02:39 PM
```

Should I be reading this purely as Time and not expecting a full date, I guess the reg property is labeled Time? Guess I am just hopeful for date but wasn't sure if there is a way to confirm it is purely a time string vs date/time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if the value you're receiving is effectively unix time ticks.

---

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the date and time:

```
[DateTime]$e = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
$t = ([DateTime]$e.AddSeconds($d)).ToString()
```

Or alternatively:

```
$t = ([datetimeoffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds($d).DateTime).ToString()
```

Expected possible result, *(locale dependent)*, using `[Int64]$d = 1594662535`:

```
PS C:\Users\ATek> Write-Host $t
07/13/2020 17:48:55
```

---

Or just the `time` only:

```
[DateTime]$e = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
$t = ([DateTime]$e.AddSeconds($d)).ToString('T')
```

Or alternatively:

```
$t = ([DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds($d).DateTime).ToString('T')
```

Expected possible result, *(locale dependent)*, using `[Int64]$d = 1594662535`:

```
PS C:\Users\ATek> Write-Host $t
17:48:55
```

Comment: Thanks for this it did the job. I also have a better understanding of time ticks because of it.